# How do I create a device specific Manifest for Android AOSP, for Suzuran - E5823 (Z5 Compact)?

Tags: android, git, manifest, sony

I'm new to Android development, and coding in general, and I'm looking to clone the AOSP Repo for the Xperia Z5 Compact. This project is my first introduction into Linux, and the first time I have used Ubuntu. (That's how new I am)

Is there any templates I could use as a guide, so I can create my own manifest, so that my Local Git has only the Projects and files I need to work on the E5823?

I'm learning how it all goes together during build; but the mass amount of files that ended up in my first git when I followed the Tutorial on the Sony Developer World & Google Source, is a little confusing when there are devices like from LG and the Nexus included in my home directory.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qW3nq.png - an example of the device directory that I want to clean up with a manifest.

Thanks,
NB